# The relation between initial boundary value problem and its adjoint problem

Tags: hyperbolic-pde

Why does the solution of the original problem exist when the solution of the adjoint boundary value problem is unique and we do not even need to prove that the solution of the adjoint boundary value problem exists?

Comment: This is a part of Fredholm alternative. Consult any reasonable linear algebra course.

Comment: The question is for wave equation, not for elliptic equation, so we cannot use Fredholm alternative theorem.

Comment: I think that you are talking about transposition method, it is just an application of Riesz representation theorem.